# Prevent duplicate entry for save smartly in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a domain named thana where I put all the thanaName. But I don't want to save any duplicate name. There may be a lot of way for doing this but which will be much smarter I don't know. Can anyone please help me on this. any example or source code will do the work perfectly. thanks in advance for watching the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the prefect use case for the [unique constraint](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Constraints/unique.html).

```
class MyDomain {
  String name
  OtherDomain related

  static constraints = {
    name unique: ['related'] // each instance must have a unique name per related
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Updated based on question in comment. The above will ensure that name is unique for each related. So, for example if MyDomain A has a related instance id of 1 and a name of "Test" no ohter instance of MyDomain with the same related instance can have the name of "Test". However, MyDomain B which has a rleated instance id of 2 can have a name of "Test" since the unique is per "related" in the above example.

Comment: Sir, thank u so much. unique works fine. But when I am giving the same name under another district it should be saved. but its not saving whether the district name is not same. how can I fix this. Can u help please ?

Comment: If you need `thanaName` to be unique, but only under specific circumstances, you'll need to implement that validation logic yourself. Have a read through the [custom validator](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Constraints/validator.html) section in the Grails docs.

Comment: @Joshua Moore thanks a lot. it works as desired. I did not watch closely before.